# How to provide Object[] as args to Assembly.CreateInstance without knowing the types before hand?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I am trying to write a program with Assembly.CreateInstance() to create an object of a class at Runtime without knowing its constructor parameter types beforehand.
Here's the class definition:

```
class SomeCode
    {
    public SomeCode(int a, string str)
        {
            Value = 1;
            Console.WriteLine( "With params" );
        }
}
```

Note: There's a few threads online about CreateInstance args , but the user already knows the args types before hand, which isn't what I want.

How to fill the

> new Object[]{}

with some values of a int and string parameter without knowing those are the parameters for the constructor?
Here's my code that is using the above class's assembly.:

```
foreach (Type T in assembly.GetTypes())
{
                Console.WriteLine( "Class Defined: " + T.FullName );
                ConstructorInfo ctor = T.GetConstructors()[0];
                ParameterInfo[] CtorParams = ctor.GetParameters();
                for (int i=0;i<CtorParams.Length;i++)
                {
                    ParameterInfo p = CtorParams[i];
                    Console.WriteLine( p.Name + ":" + p.ParameterType );
                }
                Object obj = assembly.CreateInstance(T.FullName,false,BindingFlags.Default,null,new Object[]{},null,null);
                if (obj != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine( obj.ToString() );
                }
}
```

Comment: Uh.... why are you doing this? It doesn't make a whole lot of sense to go through and try and instantiate every class in an assembly without any reason of meaning.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the question is. You know how to inspect a type's constructors (`T.GetConstructors()`). Where's your logic that says "if the parameter is an `int` then use this value", or is that not what you're trying to do?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I have this programming test that I am trying to complete which requires me to run each function in a given class. And it should work with ANY class.

Comment: @gunr2171 what if its not a known type like int, but an instance of other class?
Won't I need to provide some object value in the 'new Object[]{}' ?

Comment: "Won't I need to provide some object value in the 'new Object[]{}'" yes, you would. You'd need to know up front how to provide such a value for it. This sounds a lot like a Dependency Graph, where the DI container resolves values requested through a type's constructor. The difference is that you need to _register_ a type in the DI graph for it to be resolved - if the DI container encounters a type it doesn't know how to resolve it errors out.

Comment: @gunr2171 I see.. I will look into it more. This helps a little.